# How to change hdd read error timeout?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, kernel, bad-sectors, ddrescue

I'm recovering data from an hdd using `ddrescue`. With "retry" disabled, it takes roughly 30 seconds for every unreadable sector. The hdd has tens of thousands of bad sectors and the process is taking forever.

**Can I shorten the read error timeout to, say, 3 seconds?** Perhaps with ATA commands? Kernel options? Firmware hacks?

`smartctl` info:

```
Device Model:     Hitachi HTS542525K9A300
Firmware Version: BBFOC3EP
User Capacity:    250,059,350,016 bytes
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 3f
```

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an ancient question. Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Unfortuntely, no

Answer (score 7):

On linux, `/sys/block/<deviceName>/device/timeout` (such as `/sys/block/sda/device/timeout`) is the timeout setting in seconds, which currently defaults to 30.

In the same directory, there is a `eh_timeout` value which is used for the SCSI commands `TEST UNIT READY` and `REQUEST SENSE`, so isn't what you're looking for.

As root, `echo 1 > /sys/block/<deviceName>/device/timeout` will change the timeout to 1 second.  (Or, echo 3 for your 3 second example.)

As a non-root user, with `sudo` privileges, `sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /sys/block/<deviceName>/device/timeout"` will do the same.

Comment: Thanks!  I just used this successfully to reduce the wait time for using ddrescue on a USB connected SD card with several bad blocks.